# How to get query parameters in a Logic App?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, workflow-definition-language

I'm trying to pass an extra query parameter to Azure logic app so that I can process below data in the Logic App workflow

For Example https://logicURL?SelectedData="%7BsiteURL%3AXYZ.sharepoint.com%2Fsites%2FXYZDev%7D" (encoded string)

In HTTP action I am trying to handle above passed data with below JSON schema

```
{
    "kind": "Http",
    "inputs": {
        "schema": {
            "properties": {
                "selectedData": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "type": "object"
        }
    } }
```

I am not getting selectedData value. I need to use decodecomponentURI and then use the JSON value.

[Azure logic app schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zlb7Z.png)

Find the error here

[Azure logic app run time error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVIhX.png)

Comment: In simple words, how do I process parameter inside Azure Logic App which came through URL

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, you need to **add** your query param to the existing ones, e.g.

```
https://xyz.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/id/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-10-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=code&SelectedData="%7BsiteURL%3AXYZ.sharepoint.com%2Fsites%2FXYZDev%7D"

https://xyz.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/id/triggers/manual/paths/invoke
  ?api-version=2016-10-01
  &sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun
  &sv=1.0
  &sig=code
  &SelectedData="%7BsiteURL%3AXYZ.sharepoint.com%2Fsites%2FXYZDev%7D"
```

Then, you should be able to get them in your Logic App using

```
@triggerOutputs()['queries']['SelectedData']
```

As you can see, there is no need to add a schema to the Http Trigger to get a query parameter

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/62575372/42223 for additional caveats and a refactoring of this solution.

Answer (score 7):

### Context

- MSFT Azure Logicapp
- MSFT Logicapp workflow definition language
- Live version as of 2020-06-25 04:56:31

### Problem

- Logicapp developer wants to obtain the value of a URL query parameter passed in via HTTP GET

### Solution

- The solution to this use-case is [already provided elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51058306/42223) in this StackOverflow thread
- This addon answer, however, refactors the previous solution

  - it addresses constructing expressions in MSFT Workflow definition language (the JSON-based source code you see when viewing a logicapp in "code" view)
  - it addresses the case where a missing name-value pair can cause the entire Logicapp to terminate. We do not want that to happen, so we process name-value pairs in an error-free way

### Details

- This URL extends the original question and another answer in this SO Thread
- Here we expect `FirstName` `LastName` and `FaveColor` properties

```
    https://xyz.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/id/triggers/manual/paths/invoke
      ?api-version=2016-10-01
      &sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun
      &sv=1.0
      &sig=code
      &FirstName=Huomer
      &LastName=Huimpson
      &FaveColor=
```

- **Standard init:** The following is sufficient to capture the desired name-value pairs

```
triggerOutputs()['queries']['FirstName']
triggerOutputs()['queries']['LastName']
triggerOutputs()['queries']['FaveColor']
```

- **Error-trap init:** The following is sufficient to capture the desired name-value pairs *without* throwing an error if any desired name-value pair is missing (error-free capture)

```
triggerOutputs()['queries']?['FirstName']
triggerOutputs()['queries']?['LastName']
triggerOutputs()['queries']?['FaveColor']
```

- **Error-trap init with defaults:** The following is sufficient to error-trap init the desired name-value pairs, as well as provide a *default value* for any missing values

```
coalesce(triggerOutputs()['queries']?['FirstName']  , 'Puomer'  )
coalesce(triggerOutputs()['queries']?['LastName']   , 'Puimpson' )
coalesce(triggerOutputs()['queries']?['FaveColor']  , 'Purple' )
```

### Solution refactored

- Consequently, the original solution can be refactored as follows

```
## BEFORE
@triggerOutputs()['queries']['SelectedData']

## AFTER
@{coalesce(triggerOutputs()['queries']?['SelectedData'] , '__blank__')}
```

- This approach does what the typical use-case calls for, which is:

  - get the value if it exists,
  - otherwise provide a default value, and
  - don't crash the entire logicapp if the parameter was completely omitted
  - the `@{}` syntax can be used if you are editing workflow definition language directly, but not if you are entering it in the "expression dialog box"

### See also

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/51058306/42223
- [How to do a 'null' check in 'if' condition action of Azure Logic App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38976744/how-to-do-a-null-check-in-if-condition-action-of-azure-logic-app)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#coalesce

Comment: This is an excellent breakdown of the underlying behavior here. Thank you for the tips!

Answer (score 0):

I am sending query String as:

https://prod-17.westindia.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/f3b63b086e61420e8d76b7478f4b3e39/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-10-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=nESqZWY2NyAKKhCkaM0VnfenHuTqi1NSBjJdl9M5jNA&UserName=SecretName&Password=Nikita@123

I want to extract UserName in logic app. For that I have used Compose connector and use following statement in expression.

coalesce(triggerOutputs()['queries']?['UserName'] , '**blank**')

I have tried this to::                                                                                                       triggerOutputs()['queries']?['UserName']

But I am getting one single blank space appended in front of UserName in output. Due to which, my condition is  becoming false even if UserName is correct.

How to remove this extra space which is unnecessary appending to front.
[image]

HTTP Connector Output as :
[image]

Comment: please resubmit this question as a question .. this part of stackoverflow is intended for answers only