# How to pass a parameter to a logic app invoked from an alert

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-function-app-proxy

I have an Alert (Scheduled Query Request) that invokes an Action Group that invokes a Logic App that executes a Function App. The logic app is HTTP triggered. 
I would like to deploy the same alert on Test, Pre-Prod, Prod and pass the "environment" as a parameter from alert to the action group to the Logic App to the Function App. 
Is there a way to pass a parameter from the alert? Can you point me to a JSON sample?

Comment: If you add a parameter in the url (querystring), you should be able to access this parameter inside the logic app (see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51058306/4167200) and then pass it to the function app

Comment: Unfortunately i do not control the URL. The alert builds the URL and makes the call. Is there any way I can add a parameter in the URL from an alert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider deploying a local version of the logic app to each environment and initializing a variable with the environment name at the start of the logic app. Use parameterized ARM templates and Azure Devops to apply the proper environment value to each. It can get a [little messy mixing ARM and Logic App definitions](https://blog.mexia.com.au/preparing-azure-logic-apps-for-cicd), but it can be very rewarding in cases like these.