# LogicApp - How to check if collection is empty

Tags: azure-logic-apps

What I would like to do it if there is addOn array, I would like to append the word "xxx" to the end of the name.

```
Schema applied to message.
{
    "properties": {
        "appointment": {
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "lines": {
                    "items": {
                        "properties": {
                            "addOn": {
                                "items": {
                                    "properties": {
                                        "id": {
                                            "type": "integer"
                                        },
                                        "name": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "required": [
                                        "id",
                                        "name"
                                    ],
                                    "type": "object"
                                },
                                "type": "array"
                            },
                            "id": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "price": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            }
                        },
                        "required": [
                            "id",
                            "price"
                        ],
                        "type": "object"
                    },
                    "type": "array"
                }
            },
            "type": "object"
        },
        "messageId": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "type": "object"
}

Message 1
{
  "messageId": "11",
  "appointment": {
    "id": 22,
     "lines": [
      {
        "id": 33,
        "price": 125.0,
        "addOn": [
          {
            "id": 44,
            "name": "test"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

Message 2
{
  "messageId": "11",
  "appointment": {
    "id": 22,
     "lines": [
      {
        "id": 33,
        "price": 125.0
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Message 1 works fine but whenever I try and use length or Parse Array I get a message that addOn is null.

How can I put a proper Condition express to not get any errors or do nothing when there is no addOn array.

Logic App.
[image]

Message1 - Okay

Message2 - Error
[image]

Code View.
{
"definition": {
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
"actions": {
"For_each": {
"actions": {
"For_each_2": {
"actions": {
"Condition_3": {
"actions": {},
"expression": {
"and": [
{
"equals": [
"@empty(items('For_each_2'))",
"True"
]
}
]
},
"runAfter": {},
"type": "If"
}
},
"foreach": "@items('For_each')['addOn']",
"runAfter": {},
"type": "Foreach"
}
},
"foreach": "@body('Parse_JSON')?['appointment']?['lines']",
"runAfter": {
"Parse_JSON": [
"Succeeded"
]
},
"type": "Foreach"
},
"Parse_JSON": {
"inputs": {
"content": "@triggerBody()",
"schema": {
"properties": {
"appointment": {
"properties": {
"id": {
"type": "integer"
},
"lines": {
"items": {
"properties": {
"addOn": {
"items": {
"properties": {
"id": {
"type": "integer"
},
"name": {
"type": "string"
}
},
"required": [
"id",
"name"
],
"type": "object"
},
"type": "array"
},
"id": {
"type": "integer"
},
"price": {
"type": "integer"
}
},
"required": [
"id",
"price"
],
"type": "object"
},
"type": "array"
}
},
"type": "object"
},
"messageId": {
"type": "string"
}
},
"type": "object"
}
},
"runAfter": {},
"type": "ParseJson"
}
},
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"outputs": {},
"parameters": {},
"triggers": {
"manual": {
"inputs": {
"schema": {
"properties": {
"appointment": {
"properties": {
"id": {
"type": "integer"
},
"lines": {
"items": {
"properties": {
"addOn": {
"items": {
"properties": {
"id": {
"type": "integer"
},
"name": {
"type": "string"
}
},
"required": [
"id",
"name"
],
"type": "object"
},
"type": "array"
},
"id": {
"type": "integer"
},
"price": {
"type": "integer"
}
},
"required": [
"id",
"price",
"addOn"
],
"type": "object"
},
"type": "array"
}
},
"type": "object"
},
"messageId": {
"type": "string"
}
},
"type": "object"
}
},
"kind": "Http",
"type": "Request"
}
}
},
"parameters": {}
}

Steve

Comment: I imagine you could add some condtion as describe here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44979256/4167200

Comment: you could also make the `addOn` property required if that's an option for you ? At least you would just check if the array is empty.

Comment: Can you please try adding the code-view of your logic app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to append the word "xxx" to the end of the name.

For appending you can directly add while setting the "name" variable.

[image]

Alternatively, you can also use `concat` function as below.

```
concat(body('Parse_JSON')?['appointment']?['lines'][0]['addOn'][0]['name'],variables('xxx'))
```

[image]

where both cases would give the result as the following

[image]

> How can I put a proper Condition express to not get any errors or do nothing when there is no addOn array.

You can do this in many ways where one of the workarounds would be using if the lines contain "addOn" or not.

```
"contains": ["@body('Parse_JSON')?['appointment']?['lines'][0]","addOn"]
```

[image]

#### MESSAGE1 RESULTS:

[image]

#### MESSAGE2 RESULTS:

[image]

You can reproduce the same in your logic app using the below codeview

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Compose": {
                "inputs": "@variables('Message')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "For_each": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Condition": {
                        "actions": {
                            "Set_variable": {
                                "inputs": {
                                    "name": "Message",
                                    "value": {
                                        "appointment": {
                                            "id": "@body('Parse_JSON')?['appointment']?['id']",
                                            "lines": [
                                                {
                                                    "addOn": "addOn is NULL",
                                                    "id": "@items('For_each')?['id']",
                                                    "price": "@items('For_each')?['price']"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        "messageId": "@{body('Parse_JSON')?['messageId']}"
                                    }
                                },
                                "runAfter": {},
                                "type": "SetVariable"
                            }
                        },
                        "else": {
                            "actions": {
                                "For_each_2": {
                                    "actions": {
                                        "Set_variable_2": {
                                            "inputs": {
                                                "name": "Message",
                                                "value": {
                                                    "appointment": {
                                                        "id": "@body('Parse_JSON')?['appointment']?['id']",
                                                        "lines": [
                                                            {
                                                                "addOn": [
                                                                    {
                                                                        "id": "@items('For_each_2')?['id']",
                                                                        "name": "@{concat(body('Parse_JSON')?['appointment']?['lines'][0]['addOn'][0]['name'],variables('xxx'))}"
                                                                    }
                                                                ],
                                                                "id": "@items('For_each')?['id']",
                                                                "price": "@items('For_each')?['price']"
                                                            }
                                                        ]
                                                    },
                                                    "messageId": "@{body('Parse_JSON')?['messageId']}"
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "runAfter": {},
                                            "type": "SetVariable"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "foreach": "@items('For_each')['addOn']",
                                    "runAfter": {},
                                    "type": "Foreach"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "expression": {
                            "and": [
                                {
                                    "not": {
                                        "contains": [
                                            "@body('Parse_JSON')?['appointment']?['lines'][0]",
                                            "addOn"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "If"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@body('Parse_JSON')?['appointment']?['lines']",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable_xxx": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Message",
                            "type": "object"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_JSON": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_variable_xxx": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "xxx",
                            "type": "string",
                            "value": "xxx"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Parse_JSON": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": "@triggerBody()",
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "appointment": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "id": {
                                        "type": "integer"
                                    },
                                    "lines": {
                                        "items": {
                                            "properties": {
                                                "addOn": {
                                                    "items": {
                                                        "properties": {
                                                            "id": {
                                                                "type": "integer"
                                                            },
                                                            "name": {
                                                                "type": "string"
                                                            }
                                                        },
                                                        "required": [
                                                            "id",
                                                            "name"
                                                        ],
                                                        "type": "object"
                                                    },
                                                    "type": "array"
                                                },
                                                "id": {
                                                    "type": "integer"
                                                },
                                                "price": {
                                                    "type": "integer"
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "required": [
                                                "id",
                                                "price"
                                            ],
                                            "type": "object"
                                        },
                                        "type": "array"
                                    }
                                },
                                "type": "object"
                            },
                            "messageId": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ParseJson"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "appointment": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "id": {
                                        "type": "integer"
                                    },
                                    "lines": {
                                        "items": {
                                            "properties": {
                                                "addOn": {
                                                    "items": {
                                                        "properties": {
                                                            "id": {
                                                                "type": "integer"
                                                            },
                                                            "name": {
                                                                "type": "string"
                                                            }
                                                        },
                                                        "required": [
                                                            "id",
                                                            "name"
                                                        ],
                                                        "type": "object"
                                                    },
                                                    "type": "array"
                                                },
                                                "id": {
                                                    "type": "integer"
                                                },
                                                "price": {
                                                    "type": "integer"
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "required": [
                                                "id",
                                                "price",
                                                "addOn"
                                            ],
                                            "type": "object"
                                        },
                                        "type": "array"
                                    }
                                },
                                "type": "object"
                            },
                            "messageId": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```